# AngularJS Вывод значения

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

Контроллер:

```
$scope.locTime= function() {
$http.get('/user/time/')
.then(function(response) {
$scope.locationTime = response.data[0].locationTime;
});
```

Страница:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="locTime()">
<h1>Время пользователя</h1>
<script>
var times = //locationTime//;
console.log(times);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

В моём случае при вывод значений ангуляра, вместо фигурных скобок используется двойной слэш. Как в консоли отобразить полученное значение locationTime?

Comment: в `then` написать `console.log('LOCTIME=', response.data[0].locationTime)`

Comment: Только мне выводить обязательно на странице, а не в контроллере. Потому и такой странный вопрос. Нет никаких других возможностей передать параметр из контроллера в Javascript страницы?

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов, а если объявить переменную `times` до контроллера,  и в контроллере ей присвоить значение, а после уже вывести на самой странице.

Comment: Интересная идея. Не могли бы Вы для ясности привести пример?

Comment: У меня при всех попытка выдаёт: ReferenceError: times is not defined или TypeError: Cannot read property 'times' of undefined. То ли в контроллере переменная не видна, не понятно.

Comment: Тема закрыта. Выбран иной метод!